# How to compare two json arrays using node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

```
json1 = 
[{
        "name": "apple"
},
{
        "name": "mango"
},
{
        "name": "orange"
}]

json2 = [{
        "name": "apple"
},
{
        "name": "mango"
}]
```

I need to compare the two jsons and find out the mismatch between two json-arrays. The expected result is obviously orange. Would you please anyone help me getting this done.

Comment: What you posted are two JavaScript arrays, not JSON. JSON is a **textual, language-independent** data format, just like XML.

Comment: You can use underscore.js for comparing. For more, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24336485/underscore-compare-two-arrays-of-objects-positions

Answer (score 1):

Grab [json-diff](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-diff) from `npm` - https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-diff

Or, just have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/andreyvit/json-diff) and do whatever he did. - https://github.com/andreyvit/json-diff

Comment: The OP seems to have JavaScript arrays, not JSON.

Answer (score 1):

There are some packages out there on npm that appear to do this (https://github.com/NV/objectDiff.js).

If efficiency is not a concern, you can just do a scan, where you loop across `json1`, and for every element see if it exists in `json2`, and then vice versa. In this case, since you're only looking for these `name` KVPs, you could also just normalize it into `['apple', 'mango', 'orange']` and `['apple', 'mango']` and use `indexOf()`.